# How to get estimate shipping method in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, error, ajax

There are two problems mainly:

1. my Ajax request not firing on change of postal code in cart. don't know why
2. When I'm changing postal code on cart checkout page, Ajax request need to be fire on this URL

https://mywebsite.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/7da47754b424c67d3fe1684ab713b111/estimate-shipping-methods

the output Ajax I get is following

> [{"carrier_code":"fedex","method_code":"FEDEX_GROUND","carrier_title":"Federal
>   Express","method_title":"Ground","amount":36.24,"base_amount":36.24,"available":true,"error_message":"","price_excl_tax":36.24,"price_incl_tax":36.24},{"carrier_code":"fedex","method_code":"FEDEX_2_DAY","carrier_title":"Federal
>   Express","method_title":"2
>   Day","amount":45.94,"base_amount":45.94,"available":true,"error_message":"","price_excl_tax":45.94,"price_incl_tax":45.94},{"carrier_code":"fedex","method_code":"STANDARD_OVERNIGHT","carrier_title":"Federal
>   Express","method_title":"Standard
>   Overnight","amount":56.38,"base_amount":56.38,"available":true,"error_message":"","price_excl_tax":56.38,"price_incl_tax":56.38},{"carrier_code":"storepickup","method_code":"storepickup","carrier_title":"Store
>   Pickup","method_title":"","amount":0,"base_amount":0,"available":true,"error_message":"","price_excl_tax":0,"price_incl_tax":0}]

My question is how to get this: 7da47754b424c67d3fe1684ab713b111 code to make URL complete. if this code is wrong i enter manually I get error in Ajax

> {
>       "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
>       "parameters": {
>           "fieldName": "cartId",
>           "fieldValue": null
>       }

I'm using Magento 2.0.4

Answer (score 1):

This is the masked quote id. You can find it in the database table `quote_id_mask`